# Problema con array.indexOf() en jQuery, no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

He estado dándole vueltas a este problema y no le encuentro ninguna solución. Básicamente no me detecta ninguna coincidencia en el array.indexOf, **pero estoy seguro de que debería hacerlo**, y claro no puede ejecutar el bloque if que tiene debajo. Acepto toda clase de ayuda y gracias de antemano. Adjunto el código:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date field Test</title>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    if (date.getDate() < 10) {
                        date = date.getFullYear() + '-'
                            + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-0' + date.getDate();
                    } else {
                        date = date.getFullYear() + '-'
                            + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
                    }
                    console.log(date);
                    var array = Array('2000-01-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09');
                    console.log(array.indexOf("'" + date + "'"));
                    if (array.indexOf(date) >= 0) {
                        return [false];
                    }
                    else {
                        return [true];
                    }
                    
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas, uno es que le estas agregando una comilla simple al principio y al final que están sobrando y con eso jamás te encontrará el texto

```
array.indexOf("'" + date + "'")
// esto lo tienes que cambiar por:
array.indexOf(date)
```

ademas tienes un if-else para el número de día, si es menor a 10 le agregas un 0 al principio, te falto hacer exactamente lo mismo pero para el mes, te dejo el ejemplo

```js
const date = new Date()
let strDate = ''
if (date.getDate() < 10) {
    strDate = date.getFullYear() + '-'
        + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-0' + date.getDate();
} else {
    strDate = date.getFullYear() + '-'
        + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
}
console.log(strDate);
var array = Array('2000-01-01', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', '2020-07-09');
console.log(array.indexOf("'" + strDate + "'"));
if (array.indexOf(date) >= 0) {
    console.log(false);
}
else {
    console.log(true);
}


console.log('se agrega 0 también al mes');

// para hacerlo mas facil separare los textos
const strYear = date.getFullYear();
let strMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
if (strMonth < 10) strMonth = '0' + strMonth;

let strDay = date.getDate();
if (strDay < 10) strDay = '0' + strDay;

strDate = strYear + '-' + strMonth + '-' + strDay
console.log('texto a buscar en array:', strDate);
console.log('resultado de busqueda:', array.indexOf(strDate));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu código y por ponerme la solución delante de mis narices porque no era capaz de sacarlo xd. Menos más que existe StackOverflow, eso sí, el día que se caiga a ver quien lo arregla.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista veo varios problemas.

1. `date.getDate() < 10` : No estas poniendo el 0 del mes
2. No hace falta añadir `'` al indexOf

Dicho esto  el siguiente ejemplo podría ser una solución a tu problema.

```js
const date = new Date();
let dia = null;

//Array con los dias
const dias = ['2000-01-01', '2020-07-02', 
              '2020-07-03', '2020-07-04', 
              '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06', 
              '2020-07-07', '2020-07-08', 
              '2020-07-09'];

if(date.getDate() < 10) {
  //Ojo al primer cero del mes.
  dia = `${date.getFullYear()}-0${date.getMonth() + 1}-0${ date.getDate()}`  
}else {
  dia = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${ date.getDate()}`
}
    
console.log(dias.indexOf(dia) > -1)
```

También te recomiendo usar [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) ya que el código queda más limpio.

Espero que te sirva como ayuda.

> return [true] o [false] devolvera un array, te cuidado con eso.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda. La verdad, lo de las comillas lo había puesto por pura desesperación, ya era por probar algo. Y no se como no he caído en lo del mes, con lo fácil que parece ahora xd.